# Redirect subdomain.domain.org to domain.com which is expired

Tags: redirect, subdomain, dns-hosting, alias

I have 2 domains and both are on my server and both are registered by me. But the problem is that one of domains expired yesterday and i need to access it's data through the url urgently but i can't renew it in next few days.

So i can access both websites in my control panel and i can control everything about them, dns, subdomains, alias domains, etc...

As `domain2.com` expired, can i somehow create subdomain or alias domain of `domain2.domain1.org` and when i access that subdomain to show website from expired domain2.com.

I have tried couple of solutions with subdomains, and alias domain creation but no luck. I also tried to add a record to my DNS for `domain2.domain1.org` to point to `domain2.com`

Is there a possible way to redirect to expired domain? my control panel is ISPConfig if that matters and also i use nginx and BIND for dns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 10.1.2.3 is the IP address of your server, just add the following line to your client's hosts file:

```
10.1.2.3 domain2.com
```

...and then you'll be able to access it without issue.

Comment: Yes i know that for my own pc, but how do i explain that to my client and his workers where i don't have access to their pc's

Comment: You renew it for $12

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the hosting settings. Change the name of domain2 to xyz.domain1 in your hosting settings and give A record for xyz.domain1 in dns zone file of domain1.

This will sort out the issue.